# Why when I create a c++ class in visual studio 2013 from wizard I don't need to include headers from stdafx.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, header-files, stdafx.h

I've found curios thing which I cannot explain.
When I use class creation wizard in VS2013 it would create me .h and .cpp files with defined class basis.

Example header file:

```
#pragma once

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
};
```

Then I added some usings. I've included headers with these namespaces in stdafx. std and sf from SFML are used in my app:

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
};
```

And everything works fine. stdafx.h is not included in header file, only in .cpp.

But then I'll go with manual creation of header file(without .cpp) using same class structure:

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class SomeOtherClass
{
     public:
        SomeOtherClass();
        ~SomeOtherClass();
}
```

And it doesn't work. VS says that it can't find "sf" namespace, but there are no problems with "std" namespace.

And that's the thing which I want to know: why first case is valid and VS have found namespaces from precompiled headers and second case doesn't work.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have `using namespace X` in header files. It makes your header files troublesome for reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header files are never compiled alone. Only your `cpp` or `c` files are compiled and the header files are copied into them by the preprocessor when you `#include` them.

That means if all your cpp files where you include a header have your namespaces *before* the include of the header, it will work. Because the compiler will find the namespaces before compiling the code of the header in that file.

It's not good practice though. A header should work on it's own and not rely on the cpp file to do something before the include.

Comment: With precompiled headers, a header doesn't need to work on its own but may rely on the contents of the precompiled header. And that's made available through the .cpp